# Usage of the word "memory"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

I came across [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42683/use-of-memory) question, but I do not find the answer to what's bothering me.

Can *memory* be used to refer to a particular piece of your past experience that you remember well? E.g.:

> I have a good **memory** of putting my key on the table.

If this usage is not appropriate — what would you suggest?

Comment: Technically, there is a difference between having something in memory and having the ability to recall. You are not always able to recall all that is in your memory. You may not even be consciously aware of all that is in your memory. So, *memory* is technically incorrect -- and at the same time, the listener is not likely to understand your point either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [memory](http://www.wordnik.com/words/memory) in the sense of *[recollection](http://www.wordnik.com/words/recollect)*, then yes.

However, I would suggest that you word the sentence this way:

> I have a clear memory of putting my key on the table.

Meaning that you remember, or recollect, the action clearly.

Answer (score 5):

> there are two memories: countable - something that you remember
>   (childhood memories) and the other is uncountable - the ability to
>   remember things (memory for names) – Unreason

(posted as a comment on [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/29758/8019))

"A good memory" is only used in the second sense.  Your example is using the first sense , so 'a definite memory' or, as Gnawme says, ' a clear memory' would be usual.